# Reduction potential for reduction of O2 to H2O2 in alkaline medium

Tags: electrochemistry

I've read that $\ce{H2O2}$ is a good **reducing agent** in alkaline medium and can reduce $\ce{Fe^3+}$ ions to $\ce{Fe^2+}$ in alkaline conditions. But I need to verify this using the standard reduction potential values (at 298 K) for $\ce{Fe^3+}$ to $\ce{Fe^2+}$ and **$\ce{O2}$ to $\ce{H2O2}$(in basic conditions)**. But I haven't been able to find any reduction value for $\ce{O2}$ to $\ce{H2O2}$(in basic medium). Can someone provide me the data for this?

Comment: Search the book by the title "Oxidation Potentials" on "Internet Archive". The whole book is viewable after registration. It must have this type of information.

Comment: Can you state the name of the author, as there are multiple books with the same title.

Comment: I've tried to find it in the exhaustive list provided in Paula Atkins' Physical Chemistry, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Same issue. No reduction potential for O2 to H2O2 reduction(in basic conditions) is given.

Comment: Here is it: $\ce{O2 + 2H2O + 2e- <=> H2O2 + 2OH-} \quad E^\circ = \pu{-0.146 V}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you mention the source please?

Comment: I believe the name of the author is Latimer's "Oxidation Potentials"

Comment: The main trouble about this problem is the fact that $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ and $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ are both insoluble in alkaline conditions. So that it would be difficult to check reduction potentials as the concentrations of these ions are extremely low. In NaOH 1 M, the solubility of $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ is $\ce{2·10^{-39}}$ M, and the solubility of $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ is $\ce{8·10^{-16}}$ M, according to J. Stark,  Chemistry Data Book, John Murray London, 1982.